# Long running ajax vs polling

Tags: ajax, signalr, long-polling

I'm trying to decide what the best solution would be for my web application.  I have a page that will fire an arbitrary number of ajax requests to retrieve data from the server.  For example a page on load may fire 10 ajax requests to the server and **each** request may take 10 seconds (+-) to return content.

In view of this being a web app in a multi user and multi concurrency environment is it a good idea to use a traditional ajax approach or would you opt for long polling, such as SignalR.

What are the pros/cons of both approaches (Pull vs Push)?   Ultimately i'm after the most resource efficient approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stated example you are talking about a pure 'Pull' scenario. ie 'When the page loads I want X, Y, Z to happen and then I want to see the results'.

Long polling/websockets (SignalR) is useful for a Push scenario - ie 'Oh look I have finished running this super long process... I better tell any users currently connected'.

You can use SignalR to run those normal style AJAX requests... but you wont get any performance enhancements. The AJAX will run asynchronously and in parallel and once the server side process is complete you will a callback that executes. Perhaps you might get a slight increase in performance as signalR will have a continuous connection running, so you will loose the slight delay in creating a connection. On the flip side the server will have a large number of open connections running which may degrade performance (especially if you are hitting it with 10 X 10 sec computations)

Comment: Do you mean that having 10x10 ajax requests open will degrade the server performance?  So for this particular scenario SignalR will be the better option?

Comment: This is information that you show on the page right? For each page that loads up you need to call 10 computationally expensive calls to show data? In this case SignalR won't really help... the 10 calls will hit the server at the same time regardless - ie the problem doesn't seem to be the transport mechanism, but the long running times of the calls.

Comment: I see.  Im worried that the Ajax requests will block threads on the server.  At least with SignalR I can run the request asynchronously and push the results to the page.  Thoughts?

Comment: That might be valid. Though if every page hit is taking 100secs in total I think the server resources will be long drained before number of threads is an issue. You can use AsyncController instead of Controller and return Task<ActionResult> instead of ActionResult if you find that it is in fact the issue (.NET 4.5 is recommended for that though) or use ApiController (Web Api) and you can return a Task<T> also. This would deal with thread limits and be easier to implement in my opinion.